# Cant use Angular Package directly into IONIC 4 App

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have been trying to use Angular Masonary package on my IONIC 4 App, I am a complete beginner, and things seems a little bit frustrating trying to understand how this works from the literal HTML, CSS , JS way and the Angular , IONIC, TypeScript way.

The package is : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-masonry

it seems quite straight forward, maybe when used in Angular only.

Bottom line is: I have installed it in my IONIC 4 App, imported it into my App.Module.ts file, and then i tried using the component/method that was provided in the package Documentation.

```
<ngx-masonry>
       <div ngxMasonryItem class="masonry-item" *ngFor="let item of masonryItems">
        {{item.title}}
      </div>
</ngx-masonry>
```

When I hit save and try to reload, i get : 'ngx-masonry-item' is not a known element:
what could possibly be the cause of this ?
Please i need help.

Note: I have imported it correctly in my App.module.ts and also in my component

```
import { MasonaryComponent  } from './masonary/masonary.component';

imports: [... NgxMasonryModule],
```

Comment: Plz check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-masonry

Comment: @amir yes that was the package I initially shared.. when I opened the discussion, what happened to it.